# jQuery .on('submit', function(e) how to add extra input value + checkbox validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a simple form but I'm stuck:
if I send only the email field, the form validates the email and sends it

if I add two fields I can't get it to work:

- name
- checkbox (GDPR)

I need to add the validation that the name field is not empty, and that the checkbox field is checked

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var jsForm = $('.js-form-download');
  jsForm.on('submit', function(e) {
    var email = $(this).find('input[type=text]').val();
    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jsForm.addClass('form-error');
    }
  });
  // VALIDATION BEGIN
  function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
    return re.test(email);
  }
  //VALIDATION END
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/form.php" method="POST" class="main-download-form text-center js-form-download">

  <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="CustomFields_2_1" name="CustomFields[2]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" autocomplete="off" required="">

  <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" autocomplete="off" required="">

  <!-- field GDPR 1 REQUIRED -->
  <div class="form-single--checkbox" style="max-width:400px; margin: 0 auto 20px;">
    <label style="font-weight:normal;"><input type="checkbox" id="pcheck" style="width:18px; height: 18px; margin-left:0%;  margin-bottom:0px;"/>Accetto il Regolamento della <a href="/privacy/" style="color: #418bbd;" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>Privacy</strong></a>
    </label>
  </div>
  <input class="btn-full" type="submit" value="Continue...">
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Just add those 2 validation points in your function...

Comment: surely I am wrong something and the form is not sent

Comment: Your checkbox does not have a `name` attribute, so that won't send. Your name field has a `name` attribute of `CustomFields[2]` - not sure if that's tripping something up but it doesn't make any sense...

Comment: I added a snippet with a `</form>`

Comment: The name field (CustomFields[2]) that's what the platform I use requires

Comment: The checkbox I just need it to be checked before submitting

Comment: ... I think I send as a hidden field

Comment: thankyou @mplungjan ... ... I copied the code and forgot

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here `var email = $(this).find('input[type=text]').val();`

this will give you the **first INPUT** element's `.val()`, and if you take a closer look, the first INPUT in your form is actually the *name*

```html
<input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="CustomFields_2_1" name="CustomFields[2]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" autocomplete="off" required="">
```

So, not the *email* one.

**Instead,** use:

```js
var email = $(this).find('[name=email]').val();
```

Or, since you already use ID selectors in your HTML

```js
var email = $("#inf_field_Email").val();
```

Comment: ok @Roko , what other correct code should I add for the name field and for the checkbox?

Comment: `$(this).find('#SOMEID').val() === $('#SOMEID').val();`